# Java rx assemble result object of three async calls

Tags: rx-java2

I am trying to assemble a result object by calling three http services asynchronously. Each service will return a different field.

How do I achieve that?

I have something like this:

**Result obj**

```
public class ResultObj {
     int resStudents;
     int resClasses;
     int resGrades;
}
```

**Method**

```
      ResultObj result  = new ResultObj();


Observable.merge(studentService.fetchTotal(), classesService.fetchTotal(), gradesService.fetchTotal())
                .toBlocking();
```

What now? 
How do I get each result and set it to the ResultObj in the proper field (classes result for classes and students result for students).

for now, each fetch calll retruns Observalble of a random number.

Regards, Ido

Answer (score 0):

You should take a [look](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) at `CombineLatest`.

```
Observable.combineLatest(
    studentService.fetchTotal(),
    classesService.fetchTotal(),
    gradesService.fetchTotal(),
    (studentTotal, classesTotal, gradesTotal) -> {
        // do your stuff
        return studentTotal + classesTotal + gradesTotal;
    })
    .subscribe(
        total -> System.out.println(total)
    )
);
```

Comment: This does not run parallel. I put sleep on the first call and log prints but I see they run seraily.